# elementproblem internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, mouseover

I am using mouseoverfunction on my site and it works perfectly on firefox, chrome and safari.

But on IE9+ it cant find my mouseover function if I dont have any `background-color` on the element `div.arrow_wrap`. `Background-color:transparent` does not work either, and either does `opacity:0`. Its like `arrow_wrap` is empty. It is really wierd! In my code I have chosen the arrow icon to `fadeOut` if I have `mouseenter` on some elements and `fadeIn` if mousleave those elements. This works in IE. So why do I have to use `background-color` on my element (`div.arrow_wrap`) to get it too work in IE.

Now *I* have my arrow (`.rsArrowIcn`) to `display:none` in my css and in my javascript I have set it to `display:block` in `mouseover` function. This does work in all browsers except IE. But if remove `display:none` and choose to have it visible in my css it does work in IE. So it is really strange things that happends in IE.

I would be very thankful if someone have answer to my question! The site is: http://mlido.se/site/work/adcourse/

And my code is: http://pastebin.com/W9wrAz8n

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure it is IE 9+? It works perfectly fine in IE 9. Also, can't you format your question before posting? See how it is now.

Comment: Thanks for answering!!, but if you press one of the work cases and hold the mousepointer outside the sidebar while the page is loading. then the arrow wont show up. not for me anyway... it is only fading in if you mouseenter sidebar, logo,text content and the slideindex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

i think your in compatibility mode

go to
tools menu

select
compatibility view settings

remove your site and remove all check boxes

Comment: Thanks for answering!!, but if you press one of the work cases and hold the mousepointer outside the sidebar while the page is loading. then the arrow wont show up. not for me anyway...  it is only fading in if you mouseenter sidebar, logo,text content and the slideindex numbers..

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed on old versions of IE by setting the background to a tiled transparent gif i.e.

```
background: url(images/trans.gif);
```

Comment: I did not try the solution, i tried another thing first. I set opacity:0 on mouse icon in my css and in the mouseover function i set opacity:1 when cursor moves :)